# How to upgrade liferay services from 6.0 archetype to 6.2?

Tags: liferay, maven-3, best-fit

I am currently working on liferay upgradation from `6.0` to `6.2.2 GA3`. I tried upgrading the services portlet. The services portlet of 6.0 version is built using mvn services-portlet-archetype whereas for 6.2 version the archetype is `liferay-servicebuilder-archetype`. The difference is that in 6.2 liferay-servicebuilder-archetype there are two modules: 
`Module 1:` is a portlet which has our code logic
`Module 2:` is the services-portlet which has the class files generated during `liferay:build-service`. These files are archived into jar file which is later used inside the portlet(Module 1) module for the creation of the WAR file.

Whereas in 6.0, there is no concept of modules. The services class files generated during `liferay:build-service` are generated inside services folder under `src/`.

This `liferay-servicebuilder-archetype` is available only from `Liferay 6.1`+ versions as seen in [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.maven.archetypes/liferay-servicebuilder-archetype). My guesses for the need of this new archetype from 6.1 version are:

1. To avoid committing the auto generated services files by mistake to our version control repo.
2. To be more modular.

But with this new archetype I found out that the build process consumes lot of permgen space and heap space(I have to double the heap and permgen space everytime I run the `mvn clean package liferay:build-service` as observed through jvisualvm). I was able to create the same portlet with `services-portlet-archetype` successfully deployed and working in 6.2 GA3 server(without extra permgen space and heapspace). But did not find any memory issues during its build.

My questions are:
1. Which of these two archetypes(`liferay-servicebuilder-archetype` or `services-portlet-archetype`) is a good practice for liferay 6.2 GA3.
2. Going forward if I need to upgrade all the 20+ portlets which I am using in my project should I need to create from archetype? (Takes lot of time and effort).
3. How to fix this issue of extra memory consumption if using `liferay-servicebuilder-archetype` is the best practice. The target folder seems to produce more class files than in `services-portlet-archetype` target folder.
4. The need for this new archetype is for the two benefits mentioned above(which I guessed) or is there anything else?

Comment: Steps to upgrade can be checked from http://www.toomanylisteners.com/2015/03/steps-to-upgrade-service-builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for 2+ weeks for an answer to this question, I am assuming that my following guesses are the correct answer to this question.

```
The need for this new archetype from 6.1 version is: 
1. To avoid committing the auto generated services files by mistake to our version control repo.
2. To be more modular.
```

If there is a more convincing answer, I will choose that to be the best answer.

EDIT::::
Found this link useful
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/51303796